# Python Error Codes are upshifted

Tags: python

Consider a python script error.py

```
import sys
sys.exit(3)
```

Invoking

```
python error.py; echo $?
```

yields the expected "3". However, consider runner.py

```
import os
result = os.system("python error.py")
print result
```

yields 768. It seems that somehow the result of python code has been leftshifted by 8, but how these two situations are different is not clear. What's going on?

This is occurring in python 2.5 and 2.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system):

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
>   value of the Python function is system-dependent.
>
> os.wait()
>
> Wait for completion of a child process, and return a tuple containing
>   its pid and exit status indication: a 16-bit number, whose low byte is
>   the signal number that killed the process, and whose high byte is the
>   exit status (if the signal number is zero); the high bit of the low
>   byte is set if a core file was produced.

In your case, the return value 768 in binary is `00000011 00000000`. The high byte is 3.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Found this after digging a little more, great writeup. :)

Comment: Though one question, in posix, why is the PID of the child process always 0?

Comment: You're not getting a PID back from `os.system` because it waits for the subprocess to finish, only the 16-bit number as specified in `wait`. Use `os.popen` or the `subprocess` module if you want to spawn an async subprocess with a lasting PID.

Answer (score 5):

## Docs

[`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait()

[`os.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.wait)

> a 16-bit
>   number, whose low byte is the signal number that killed the process,
>   and whose high byte is the exit status (if the signal number is zero)

---

### High/low byte for 768

```
00000011 00000000
 status   signal
```

---

### Specific code

It should be safe to `>> 8` the result to get your actual exit status (the result of `system()` isn't very portable across platforms, however).

```
import os
result = os.system("python error.py")
print result >> 8
```