# Catching runtime errors in application executed by os.system

Tags: python

In my application, os.system is used to execute another program.

```
os.system('./appln')
```

Is there any way to detect if a runtime error occurs in the program being executed [ for example, like a SIGSEGV]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`. The `subprocess` module has a number of ways to capture return codes or raise exceptions on non-zero return codes:  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system

Comment: I would have gone with that, but the code is already written and all I can do is to find something that I can do with os.system :(

Comment: @ersran9: The subprocess module is in the standard library. There's nothing to install, you already have it. You just need to convert the code.

Answer (score 0):

By checking the return values of the os.system call, it is possible to detect runtime errors in the program being executed. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466711/what-is-return-of-os-system-in-python) details the various return values of os.system call.

That said, it is better to follow @tweet's answer and use subprocess module instead to achieve the same.