# os.waitpid doesn't return a tuple containing pid, and its exit status

Tags: python, process, wait

I try to come up with a workaround for this [python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue3905) calling `subprocess`. I figured the way to go is using `os.system` in combination with `os.waitpid`. To test this I wrote the code below. `system_call_test.py` writes the `pid` and lot's of text to the file `f`. But calling `os.waitpid()` always get me this error: `OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes`. So I'm having a hard time to check if this construct is working properly. How can I ensure that the script waits for the termination of the other. I'm on windows XP/ python 2.7.

```
import os
f = r'D:\temp\called.txt'

s = os.system('C:\Python27\python.exe D:\python_spullen\system_call_test.py')
with open(f, 'r') as f_in:
    i = f_in.readline()[-4:]
    print i
    rr = os.waitpid(int(i),0)
    print rr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` returns [the exit code of the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466711/what-is-return-of-os-system-in-python). So `s` above is already populated and the process has exited. `os.waitpid` has nothing to wait on.

Comment: So when the exit code is  `0`, the process has terminated without errors?

Answer (score 1):

`system()` is a combine of `fork()` + `exec()` + `waitpid()`. You should not call `waitpid()` again.