# Extra zero after executing a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to execute a python script from another and storing the output value in a variable.

When I do this:

```
import os

test = os.system("/usr/local/bin/script1.py")
print test;
```

and then execute the script I get an extra zero on the results:

```
$ ./test.py
171
0
```

script1.py does produce "171" as the output, but not sure where the extra zero is coming from... Any ideas?

Comment: Print it in script1.py file and you won't get the 0 at end

Comment: @guisantogui: The basic idea is not to print this value anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is return of os.system() in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466711/what-is-return-of-os-system-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [exit status](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) of the command.

`help(os.system)`:

```
system(...)
    system(command) -> exit_status

    Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.
```

> On Unix, the return value is the **exit status** of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
>   value of the Python function is system-dependent.

---

It's better to [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) if you want to store the output of a command in a variable.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any better way to do it other than using os.system()?

Comment: @OmarSantos As the docs suggest, use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

Comment: @OmarSantos Use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to get the output of a command.

Answer (score 2):

The zero is the return code from the command, which you are assigning to `test` and then printing. (Zero means that no error occurred.)

If you don't know what it is, why are you printing it?

Comment: Thank you! I just want to store the output of the first script in a variable. Is there any better way to do it instead of os.system()?

Comment: Yes—as [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.system) says, you should be using the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  I've #!'d to CPython 3.3, but 2.x should work too:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import subprocess

test = subprocess.check_output(args=["echo", "171"])
print(test)
```