# Storing value from a parsed ping

Tags: python, linux, awk

I'm working on some code that performs a ping operation from python and extracts only the latency by using awk. This is currently what I have:

```
from os import system
l = system("ping -c 1 sitename | awk -F = 'FNR==2 {print substr($4,1,length($4)-3)}'")
print l
```

The `system()` call works fine, but I get an output in terminal rather than the value storing into l. Basically, an example output I'd get from this particular block of code would be

```
90.3
0
```

Why does this happen, and how would I go about actually storing that value into l? This is part of a larger thing I'm working on, so preferably I'd like to keep it in native python.

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: I'm currently running Python 2.7

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't it be easier to do the string parsing in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) if you want to store the output in a variable:

```
from subprocess import check_output
l = check_output("ping -c 1 sitename | awk -F = 'FNR==2 {print substr($4,1,length($4)-3)}'", shell=True) 
print l
```

Related: [Extra zero after executing a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914292/extra-zero-after-executing-a-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

`os.system()` returns the return code of the called command, not the output to stdout.

For detail on how to properly get the command's output (including pre-Python 2.7), see this: [Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 1):

BTW I would use Ping Package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping

It looks promising

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I store output to a variable.

```
test=$(ping -c 1 google.com | awk -F"=| " 'NR==2 {print $11}')
echo "$test"
34.9
```