# Printing part of a string in Python

Tags: python-2.7, substring

Trying to obtain and print and further use just the local ip address on a pi:

```
import os
getipaddr = "ip addr show eth0 | grep inet"
ip = "%s" % (os.system(getipaddr))
print ip
```

returns:

> inet 192.168.1.200/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
>   0

which correctly includes the local address, but:

```
import os
getipaddr = "ip addr show eth0 | grep inet"
ip = "%s" % (os.system(getipaddr))
print ip[9:22]
```

returns:

> inet 192.168.1.200/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0

not my expected subset of characters from character 10 to 21.  Maybe ip is not really a string variable.  Any help on how to fix greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
[note: there are actually 4 spaces in front of inet in the print returns, just don't know how to show it in this forum]

Comment: Not sure what's causing your problem, but since the IP is technically variable length, I should think a regular expression is more suited to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466711/what-is-return-of-os-system-in-python), you will see that the return value of `os.system` is the return value of the call, not it's output.  The output you are seeing on the screen is not coming from python but from the `ip` call.  If you want to capture output use the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import check_output
getipaddr = "ip addr show eth0 | grep inet"
ip = check_output(getipaddr, shell=True)
```

Now, the output will be in `ip` and you should get your desired results.

---

As a side note, `'%s' % something` is an anti-pattern.  The clearer way to convert a string is to do `str(something)`.

Comment: Thank you Seth!  I'm learning...  I'll look up "anti-pattern"