# Return value of x = os.system(..)

Tags: python, linux, os.system

When I type `os.system("whoami")` in Python, as root, it returns `root`, but when I try to assign it to a variable `x = os.system("whoami")` it set's the value of x to 0. Why ? (:

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) returns the (encoded) process exit value. `0` means success:

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for `wait()`. Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return value of the Python function is system-dependent.

The output you see is written to `stdout`, so your console or terminal, and not returned to the Python caller.

If you wanted to capture `stdout`, use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead:

```
x = subprocess.check_output(['whoami'])
```

Answer (score 8):

`os.system('command')` returns a 16 bit number, which first 8 bits from left(lsb) talks about signal used by os to close the command, Next 8 bits talks about return code of command.

Refer my answer for more detail in [What is the return value of os.system() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466711/what-is-the-return-value-of-os-system-in-python/35362488#35362488)