# How to print a statement based on hydra result in python?

Tags: python, hydra

I updated the code but there still seems to have an error.

```
import os
import subprocess

name = raw_input("\nWHO DO WE HACK? ")

passw = subprocess_check.input(['hydra -l ' + name + ' -P pss.txt smb://192.168.66.128'])

print passw
if passw == '0':
    print "HELLO"
else:
    print "NOT"
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.system()` doesn' work like that. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005583/return-value-of-x-os-system). You're getting the return code, not the command output. 0 means that the process exited without errors. Use the `subprocess` module to get the command output.