# Why is a 0 returned in system date?

Tags: python

While executing the below script in the interactive prompt, there is an additional 0 is returned. Why is that 0 there?

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('date')
Sun Oct  2 19:20:29 IST 2016  
0
```

Comment: per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005583/return-value-of-x-os-system 0 means success.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: The function prints the time and then return `0`.
Try  `a = os.system('date')`  
You won't see the zero now.  
Now check the value of a and you will find it `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats the exit status of the program, `0` normally means the program finished without error.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing a system call. 0 is the return code of this call.
If you are trying to just get the current time use:
    datetime.datetime.now()