# Empty variables when working with OS library

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I tried multiple times to make this work without results, here's the code

```py
import os, sys

try:
    with open("syscore.lib", "r") as confFile:
        readConfFile = confFile.readlines()
        fileExist = True                                                  
except:
    fileExist = False

if fileExist is True:
    method = "r"
else:
    method = "w"                                                          
for _ in range(2):
    with open("syscore.lib", method) as confFile:
        try:
            readConfFile = confFile.readlines()
    except:
        confFile.write(os.system("python --version").replace("Python ", ""))
print(readConfFile)
```

The problem come again in a similar way down here

```py
import os

test = [str(os.system('python --version'))]
test1 = os.system('python --version')

print('PV: '+str(test1))
print('Python Version: '+test[0])
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the expected file content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the relevant thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005583/return-value-of-x-os-system), `os.system()` returns the process exit value. `0` means success. If you want to capture the printed output, use `os.popen()` instead:

```
import os


python_version = os.popen("python -V").read().strip()
```

And the output is `'Python 3.6.6'`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `os.popen()` is not particularly brilliant, it's just a wrapper for the proper functionality. You want `subprocess.check_output()` but of course calling Python in a subprocess from Python itself to find its version number is just silly.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get python version then try,

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> version = "{}.{}.{}".format(*sys.version_info)
'2.7.12'
>>>
```

you will get in python3,

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> "{}.{}.{}".format(*sys.version_info)
'3.5.2'
>>>
```

or you can use,

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
>>>
```