# Python: Parse terminal response

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, rclone

I want to write a script for automatic backing up some documents on my raspberry pi to a google drive. Therefore I installed rclone and it seems to work well.
For organisation purpose I want to create for every upload a new folder with a 3 digit number e.g 001, 002, 003, ...
This is my code so far:

```
import os

print("Exisiting folders:")
print(os.system("rclone lsf backup_account:backup"))

print("Create new folder...")
createFolder = os.system("rclone mkdir backup_account:backup/003")

print("Exisiting folders:")

folders = str(os.system("rclone lsf backup_account:backup"))
print(type(folders))
print(len(folders))
```

**First** I print the already existing folders in the google drive directory "backup".
**Second** I create a new folder (in this example it is a static number and will be changed to a dynamic one, once the rest is working)
**Third** I print the existing folders once again to check if everything worked fine.

Up to here, everything indeed works well and i get a printout like this:

```
Existing folders:
001/
002/
0
Create new folder...
Existing folders:
001/
002/
003/
<type 'str'>
1
```

As you see, it gives the folders as a string, if i leave out the Str() it returns a int.
what I don't understand is, that the len(folders) = 1.

What I want is: Check in the beginning the existing folders and create a new one(following the numbering schema) and then copy the backup files to this new folder.
As the script wont be running all the time, i cannot store anything in a variable.

Any hints on how to put the existing folders into a list, array, ... to find the last element/highest number/...?

**Running raspbian buster**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return value of x = os.system(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005583/return-value-of-x-os-system)

Comment: Please check the return value of `os.system("rclone lsf backup_account:backup")`.

Comment: Using the proposed code:
`x = subprocess.check_output(['whoami'])` returns a correct value.

Comment: If copy paste `rclone lsf backup_account:backup` it returns:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backup.py", line 18, in <module>
    x = subprocess.check_output(['rclone lsf boxer3000:backup'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 216, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`