# Python os.system grep different results than bash grep

Tags: python

I'm turning a bash script into python, but when do this in python:

```
cmd = r"grep 'name' somefile.log | grep -v 'result=""' | grep -v result='is\ OK'"
results_str = os.system(cmd)
print (results_str,"\n")
```

I don't get any output of grep. If I run it from the command line/bash, I get

```
grep 'name' somefile.log | grep -v 'result=""' | grep -v result='is\ OK'
name="blah", result="the thing I'm trying to grep", action="", info=""
```

What is wrong with my python grep?

Comment: `os.system` doesn't return the value you are expecting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26005591/11424673 it returns the process exit value, not any standard output

Answer (score 0):

Use - `os.popen()`

`os.popen()` gives you control over the process's input or output file streams. `os.system()` doesn't. If you don't need to access the process's I/O, you can use `os.system()` for simplicity.

So your revised code will be -

```
cmd = r"grep 'name' somefile.log | grep -v 'result=""' | grep -v result='is\ OK'"
results_str = os.popen(cmd)
print (results_str,"\n")
```

Comment: `os.popen()` does not return standard output, either.

Comment: os.open(cmd) gives error `<os._wrap_close object at 0x7f9040176da0>`, no idea what that means