# How to determine whether a program run through Python (ideally with subprocess) crashed or ended successfully

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to test some programs by using Python. I want to see if given certain input they crash, end without errors, or run for longer than a timeout.

Ideally I would like to use subprocess as I am familiar with that. However am able to use any other useful library. I assume that reading core dump notifications is an option, however I do not yet know how to do that  nor do I know if that is the most effective way.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your request. I don't know what code to try. I read the subprocess manual and did not see any way to see if the program ended in an error.

Comment: You can start by calling a python script using subprocess and raise an error / exit the called python script.

Comment: you can use logging, flags or any notify packages to get the status of the running script.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636561 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374. You could start a sub-process in a separate thread with a timeout. Checking the exit code is pretty straightforward once it's done.

Comment: @Jeril , Sure, I did that. I don't see how that helps as I don't know what to read from that. I did print(subprocess.call("<location to program that crashes>")) . Can you be more blunt as to what you are suggesting? I don't understand your hints.

Comment: @ArunAugustine I don't see how polling would help as a program can end either with no error (but return a non-zero value) or by causing through eg. a segfault

Comment: @kingkupps see my response to ArunAugstine

Answer (score 0):

Using `os` and [What is the return value of os.system() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466711/what-is-the-return-value-of-os-system-in-python/35362488#35362488), a solution could be:

```
status = os.system(cmd)
# status is a 16 bit number, which first 8 bits from left(lsb) talks about signal used by os to close the command, Next 8 bits talks about return code of command.
sig, ret = os.WIFSIGNALED(status), os.WEXITSTATUS(status)
# then check some usual problems:
if sig:
    if status == 11:      # SIGSEGV
        print ('crashed by segfault')
    elif status == 6 :    # SIGABRT
        print('was aborted')
    else: # 14, 9 are related to timeouts if you like them
        print('was stopped abnormally with', status)
else:
    print('program finished properly')
```

I haven't checked yet if subprocess returns the same status.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It appears to do what I require. For some reason I get status 139 when running a program that ends in SIGSEV . Any idea why?

Comment: A program that ends in SIGFPE causes status 136. I guess that there is an offset

Comment: The offset is 128, that's a convention when a program is stopped by a signal (linux or bash convention I don't remember; it is probably explained on SO somewhere). I must have over-simplified my code snippet...

Comment: Upon further testing I realize that if the program ends in an exception, I can tell which one it is by using the table here:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm
However, if the program finished without an exception, but returned a non-zero value, then I cannot tell the difference between that and a program that crashed.